# Error when exporting SOAP Server Object Extension from Eclipse plugin

Tags: arcgis-server, server-object-extension

I am new to creating SOEs. Limited experience with ArcObjects. We are upgrading from ArcGIS server 10.05 to 10.3 and I am responsible for wrapping all of our code (Java) in SOEs for the upgrade since the code currently uses a DCOM connection. I have found very little documentation on the specifics of writing SOEs but have installed the Eclipse plugin (Ver 10.3.1.4959) in Rational Application Developer (RAD 9.6) as instructed to be able to create and export the SOEs. The documentation that I have been following is ESRI’s ArcObjects Help for Java – Developing Extensions.

I am getting errors when trying to export a SOAP SOE using the plugin. It appears to export everything else but fails when it is exporting the actual soe file. Error: “javac” terminated with errors.

The one resolution for this that I found is setting your PATH variable. I tried that, it doesn’t resolve my issue.  Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

NOTE: I have also asked this question on GeoNet community and have not received any response.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up contacting ESRI on this. There is a bug in the ArcObjects Eclipse plugin for ArcGIS 10.3. What I ended up having to do is install Eclipse Neon, JDK 1.7u76, and use the Eclipse plugin from ArcGIS 10.5. I was then able to export a SOAP SOE succcessfully.

Using the JDK 1.7U76 made the SOE backwards compatible with ArcGIS Server 10.3